# ffmpeg undefined reference to sws_getContext

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am learning to use ffmpeg libraries, and have successfully compiled and run a program that demuxes and decodes a video. However, when I was trying to use the swscale library, I got a linking error "undefined reference to sws_getContext". There are similar problems on the Internet but none of them solves my problem.

The full error message is

```sh
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ffmpeg_test.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x44f): undefined reference to `sws_getContext'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ffmpeg_test.dir/build.make:93: ffmpeg_test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/ffmpeg_test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Here is my Dockerfile, source file and CMakeList.

```
# FFMPEG Image
# ref：https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

FROM ubuntu:20.04

ARG http_proxy=''
ARG https_proxy=''
ENV HTTP_PROXY=${http_proxy}
ENV HTTPS_PROXY=${https_proxy}

RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        autoconf \
        automake \
        build-essential \
        cmake \
        git \
        libass-dev \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libgnutls28-dev \
        # libsdl2-dev \
        libtool \
        # libva-dev \
        # libvdpau-dev \
        libvorbis-dev \
        # libxcb1-dev \
        # libxcb-shm0-dev \
        # libxcb-xfixes0-dev \
        meson \
        ninja-build \
        pkg-config \
        texinfo \
        wget \
        yasm \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libunistring-dev \
        python3.8-dev \
        ca-certificates

ARG FFMPEG_ROOT=/root/ffmpeg
RUN mkdir ${FFMPEG_ROOT}
WORKDIR ${FFMPEG_ROOT}

RUN mkdir sources && mkdir build && mkdir bin

# NASM
RUN cd sources \
    && wget https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.15.05/nasm-2.15.05.tar.bz2 \
    && tar xjvf nasm-2.15.05.tar.bz2 \
    && cd nasm-2.15.05 \
    && ./autogen.sh \
    && PATH="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/bin:$PATH" \
        ./configure \
            --prefix="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/build" \
            --bindir="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/bin" \
            --enable-shared \
            --enable-pic \
    && make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install

# H.264 video encoder (GPL License!!!  --enable-gpl --enable-libx264)
RUN cd sources \
    && git -C x264 pull 2> /dev/null || git clone --depth 1 https://code.videolan.org/videolan/x264.git \
    && cd x264 \
    && PATH="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/bin:$PATH" \
        PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/build/lib/pkgconfig" \
        ./configure \
            --prefix="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/build" \
            --bindir="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/bin" \
            --enable-shared \
            --enable-pic \
            --disable-cli \
    && PATH="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/bin:$PATH" make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install

# H.265/HEVC video encoder (GPL License!!!  --enable-gpl --enable-libx265)
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libnuma-dev \
    && cd sources \
    && git -C x265_git pull 2> /dev/null || git clone https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265_git \
    && cd x265_git/build/linux \
    && PATH="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/bin:$PATH" \
        cmake \
            -G "Unix Makefiles" \
            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/build" \
            -DENABLE_SHARED=on \
            -DENABLE_CLI=off \
            ../../source \
    && PATH="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/bin:$PATH" make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install

# VP8/VP9 video encoder/decoder (--enable-libvpx)
RUN cd sources \
    && git -C libvpx pull 2> /dev/null || git clone --depth 1 https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/libvpx.git \
    && cd libvpx \
    && PATH="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/bin:$PATH" \
        ./configure \
            --prefix="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/build" \
            --disable-debug \
            --disable-examples \
            --disable-docs \
            --disable-unit-tests \
            --enable-vp9-highbitdepth \
            --as=yasm \
            --enable-pic \
            --enable-shared \
    && PATH="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/bin:$PATH" make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install

# # AAC audio encoder (NON-FREE!!!  --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac)
# RUN cd sources \
#     && git -C fdk-aac pull 2> /dev/null || git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac \
#     && cd fdk-aac \
#     && autoreconf -fiv \
#     && ./configure \
#         --prefix="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/build" \
#         --disable-shared \
#     && make -j$(nproc) \
#     && make install

# MP3 audio encoder (--enable-libmp3lame)
RUN cd sources \
    && wget -O lame-3.100.tar.gz https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/lame/lame/3.100/lame-3.100.tar.gz \
    && tar xzvf lame-3.100.tar.gz \
    && cd lame-3.100 \
    && PATH="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/bin:$PATH" \
        ./configure \
        --prefix="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/build" \
        --bindir="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/bin" \
        --enable-shared \
        --enable-pic \
        --enable-nasm \
    && PATH="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/bin:$PATH" make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install

# Opus audio decoder and encoder (--enable-libopus)
RUN cd sources \
    && git -C opus pull 2> /dev/null || git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/xiph/opus.git \
    && cd opus \
    && ./autogen.sh \
    && ./configure \
        --prefix="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/build" \
        --enable-shared \
    && make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install

# AV1 video encoder/decoder
# encoder (--enable-libsvtav1)
RUN cd sources \
    && git -C SVT-AV1 pull 2> /dev/null || git clone https://gitlab.com/AOMediaCodec/SVT-AV1.git \
    && mkdir -p SVT-AV1/build \
    && cd SVT-AV1/build \
    && PATH="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/bin:$PATH" \
        cmake \
            -G "Unix Makefiles" \
            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/build" \
            -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
            -DBUILD_DEC=OFF \
            -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
            .. \
    && PATH="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/bin:$PATH" make -j$(nproc)\
    && make install
# decoder (--enable-libdav1d)
RUN cd sources \
    && git -C dav1d pull 2> /dev/null || git clone --depth 1 https://code.videolan.org/videolan/dav1d.git \
    && mkdir -p dav1d/build \
    && cd dav1d/build \
    && PATH="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/bin:$PATH" \
        meson setup \
            -Denable_tools=false \
            -Denable_tests=false \
            --default-library=shared \
            .. \
            --prefix="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/build" \
            --libdir="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/build/lib" \
    && ninja -j$(nproc) \
    && ninja install

# Library for calculating the ​VMAF video quality metric (--enable-libvmaf --ld="g++")
RUN cd sources \
    && wget https://github.com/Netflix/vmaf/archive/v2.1.1.tar.gz \
    && tar xvf v2.1.1.tar.gz \
    && mkdir -p vmaf-2.1.1/libvmaf/build \
    && cd vmaf-2.1.1/libvmaf/build \
    && PATH="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/bin:$PATH" \
        meson setup \
            -Denable_tests=false \
            -Denable_docs=false \
            --buildtype=release \
            --default-library=shared \
            .. \
            --prefix "${FFMPEG_ROOT}/build" \
            --bindir="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/build/bin" \
            --libdir="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/build/lib" \
    && ninja -j$(nproc) \
    && ninja install

# FFMPEG
RUN cd sources \
    && wget -O ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 \
    && tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 \
    && cd ffmpeg \
    && PATH="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/bin:$PATH" \
        PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/build/lib/pkgconfig" \
        ./configure \
            --prefix="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/build" \
            --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
            --extra-cflags="-I${FFMPEG_ROOT}/build/include" \
            --extra-ldflags="-L${FFMPEG_ROOT}/build/lib" \
            --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
            --ld="g++" \
            --bindir="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/bin" \
            --disable-debug \
            --disable-doc \
            --disable-ffplay \
            --enable-shared \
            --enable-pic \
            --enable-gpl \
            --enable-gnutls \
            # --enable-libaom \
            --enable-libass \
            # --enable-libfdk-aac \
            --enable-libfreetype \
            --enable-libmp3lame \
            --enable-libopus \
            --enable-libsvtav1 \
            --enable-libdav1d \
            --enable-libvorbis \
            --enable-libvpx \
            --enable-libx264 \
            --enable-libx265 \
            # --enable-nonfree \
    && PATH="${FFMPEG_ROOT}/bin:$PATH" make -j$(nproc) \
    && make install \
    && hash -r

# opencv
RUN apt-get update \
    & apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libopencv-dev
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
#include <libavutil/avutil.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

// fix c++ av_err2str problem
// ref: https://github.com/joncampbell123/composite-video-simulator/issues/5
#ifdef av_err2str
#undef av_err2str
#include <string>
av_always_inline std::string av_err2string(int errnum) {
    char str[AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    return av_make_error_string(str, AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE, errnum);
}
#define av_err2str(err) av_err2string(err).c_str()
#endif  // av_err2str


static int decode_packet(AVPacket *, AVCodecContext *, AVFrame *, AVStream *);


int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
    AVFormatContext *pFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();

    if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatContext, argv[1], NULL, NULL) != 0) {
        std::cout << "ERROR could not open the file\n";
        return -1;
    }

    printf("File format %s, duration %.2fs, bit_rate %ld\n", pFormatContext->iformat->long_name, pFormatContext->duration / 1e6, pFormatContext->bit_rate);

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatContext,  NULL) < 0) {
        std::cout << "ERROR could not get the stream info\n";
        return -1;
    }

    int video_stream_index = -1;

    printf("Number of streams %d\n", pFormatContext->nb_streams);

    AVCodecParameters *pVideoCodecParameters;
    const AVCodec *pVideoCodec;
    AVStream *pVideoStream;

    for (int i = 0; i < pFormatContext->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        AVCodecParameters *pLocalCodecParameters = pFormatContext->streams[i]->codecpar;
        const AVCodec *pLocalCodec = NULL;
        pLocalCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(pLocalCodecParameters->codec_id);

        // print its name and bitrate
        printf("Codec %s, bit_rate %ld\n", pLocalCodec->long_name, pLocalCodecParameters->bit_rate);

        if (pLocalCodecParameters->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            if (video_stream_index == -1) {
                video_stream_index = i;
                pVideoCodecParameters = pLocalCodecParameters;
                pVideoCodec = pLocalCodec;
            }
            pVideoStream = pFormatContext->streams[i];
            AVRational *fps = &pVideoStream->avg_frame_rate;
            AVRational *rfps = &pVideoStream->r_frame_rate;
            AVRational *time_base = &pVideoStream->time_base;
            printf("Video Codec: resolution %d x %d, fps %d/%d, frames %ld, time base %d/%d, rfps %d/%d\n", 
                pLocalCodecParameters->width, pLocalCodecParameters->height, 
                fps->num, fps->den, pVideoStream->nb_frames, time_base->num, time_base->den,
                rfps->num, rfps->den);
        } else if (pLocalCodecParameters->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            printf("Audio Codec: %d channels, sample rate %d\n", pLocalCodecParameters->channels, pLocalCodecParameters->sample_rate);
        }
        
        if (pLocalCodec==NULL) {
            printf("ERROR unsupported codec!\n");
            // In this example if the codec is not found we just skip it
            continue;
        }
    }

    if (video_stream_index == -1) {
        printf("File %s does not contain a video stream!\n", argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    AVCodecContext *pCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(pVideoCodec);
    if (!pCodecContext)
    {
        printf("failed to allocated memory for AVCodecContext\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (avcodec_parameters_to_context(pCodecContext, pVideoCodecParameters) < 0)
    {
        printf("failed to copy codec params to codec context\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (avcodec_open2(pCodecContext, pVideoCodec, NULL) < 0)
    {
        printf("failed to open codec through avcodec_open2\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVPacket.html
    AVPacket *pPacket = av_packet_alloc();
    if (!pPacket)
    {
        printf("failed to allocated memory for AVPacket\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    // https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVFrame.html
    AVFrame *pFrame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!pFrame)
    {
        printf("failed to allocated memory for AVFrame\n");
        return -1;
    }

    SwsContext *pImgConvertContext = sws_getContext(
        pCodecContext->width,
        pCodecContext->height,
        pCodecContext->pix_fmt,
        pCodecContext->width,
        pCodecContext->height,
        AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,
        SWS_BICUBIC,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL
    );

    int response = 0;
    int how_many_packets_to_process = 8;

    // fill the Packet with data from the Stream
    // https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html#ga4fdb3084415a82e3810de6ee60e46a61
    while (av_read_frame(pFormatContext, pPacket) >= 0)
    {
        // if it's the video stream
        if (pPacket->stream_index == video_stream_index) {
            printf("AVPacket->pts %" PRId64, pPacket->pts);
            std::cout << std::endl;
            response = decode_packet(pPacket, pCodecContext, pFrame, pVideoStream);
            if (response < 0)
                break;
            // stop it, otherwise we'll be saving hundreds of frames
            if (--how_many_packets_to_process <= 0) break;
        }
        // https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__packet.html#ga63d5a489b419bd5d45cfd09091cbcbc2
        av_packet_unref(pPacket);
    }

    avformat_close_input(&pFormatContext);
    av_packet_free(&pPacket);
    av_frame_free(&pFrame);
    avcodec_free_context(&pCodecContext);

    std::cout << "bye world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

static int decode_packet(AVPacket *pPacket, AVCodecContext *pCodecContext, AVFrame *pFrame, AVStream *pStream)
{
    // Supply raw packet data as input to a decoder
    // https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__decoding.html#ga58bc4bf1e0ac59e27362597e467efff3
    int response = avcodec_send_packet(pCodecContext, pPacket);
    // printf("response %d\n", response);

    if (response < 0) {
        printf("Error while sending a packet to the decoder: %s\n", av_err2str(response));
        return response;
    }

    while (response >= 0)
    {
        // Return decoded output data (into a frame) from a decoder
        // https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__decoding.html#ga11e6542c4e66d3028668788a1a74217c
        response = avcodec_receive_frame(pCodecContext, pFrame);
        if (response == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || response == AVERROR_EOF) {
            break;
        } else if (response < 0) {
            printf("Error while receiving a frame from the decoder: %s\n", av_err2str(response));
            return response;
        }

        if (response >= 0) {
            float time_base = pStream->time_base.num / float(pStream->time_base.den);
            printf(
                "Frame %d (type=%c, size=%d bytes, format=%d) pts %ld timestampe %.2f key_frame %d [DTS %d]\n",
                pCodecContext->frame_number,
                av_get_picture_type_char(pFrame->pict_type),
                pFrame->pkt_size,
                pFrame->format,
                pFrame->pts,
                pFrame->pts * time_base,
                pFrame->key_frame,
                pFrame->coded_picture_number
            );

        // char frame_filename[1024];
        // snprintf(frame_filename, sizeof(frame_filename), "%s-%d.pgm", "frame", pCodecContext->frame_number);
        // Check if the frame is a planar YUV 4:2:0, 12bpp
        // That is the format of the provided .mp4 file
        // RGB formats will definitely not give a gray image
        // Other YUV image may do so, but untested, so give a warning
        // if (pFrame->format != AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P)
        // {
        //     printf("Warning: the generated file may not be a grayscale image, but could e.g. be just the R component if the video format is RGB");
        // }
        // save a grayscale frame into a .pgm file
        // save_gray_frame(pFrame->data[0], pFrame->linesize[0], pFrame->width, pFrame->height, frame_filename);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# set the project name
project(ffmpeg_test)

# specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

# add the executable
add_executable(ffmpeg_test main.cpp)

# link ffmpeg
set(FFMPEG_ROOT "/root/ffmpeg/build")

target_include_directories(ffmpeg_test PUBLIC "${FFMPEG_ROOT}/include")
target_link_libraries(ffmpeg_test 
    "${FFMPEG_ROOT}/lib/libavutil.so"
    "${FFMPEG_ROOT}/lib/libpostproc.so"
    "${FFMPEG_ROOT}/lib/libswresample.so"
    "${FFMPEG_ROOT}/lib/libswscale.so"
    "${FFMPEG_ROOT}/lib/libavfilter.so"
    "${FFMPEG_ROOT}/lib/libavdevice.so"
    "${FFMPEG_ROOT}/lib/libavformat.so"
    "${FFMPEG_ROOT}/lib/libavcodec.so"
)

# link opencv
target_include_directories(ffmpeg_test PUBLIC "/usr/include/opencv4")
target_link_libraries(ffmpeg_test 
    "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so"
)
# find_library(OpenCV REQUIRED)
# message(STATUS ${OpenCV_VERSION})
# message(STATUS ${OpenCV_LIBS})
# message(STATUS ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Comment: please provide the full error message

Comment: @AlanBirtles error message added

Comment: Use the latest version of FFmpeg.

Comment: @thekamilz just checked that my ffmpeg is the latest version, version 4.4

Comment: Can you try to manually link (LD/GCC) your ffmpeg_test file including `-lswscale` ? (Yes before that you need to give location with `-L/ffmpeg/library/path`).

Comment: @thekamilz if I run g++ ../src/main.cpp -L/root/ffmpeg/build/lib/ -I/root/ffmpeg/build/include/ -lpostproc -lswresample -lswscale -lavfilter -lavdevice -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -ldav1d -lSvtAv1Enc -lx264 -lx265, I will get /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccf6cZIx.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x44f): undefined reference to `sws_getContext'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @thekamilz could it be caused by some wrong configuration of the compilation of FFMPEG?

Comment: Yes, but it shouldn't. Try to move `lswscale` on your line on the previous comment back and forth. See if it changes anything.

Comment: @thekamilz I have found the problem. I used `nm -D libswscale.so > libswscale.txt` to see the content of `libswscale.so`. It turned out that the content of `libswscale.so` is the same as the content of `libswresample.so`. Thought I don't know what caused this problem, after rebuilding the docker image, the problem was solved. Thanks for your time!